# What happens when ld link different versions of the same library

Tags: c++, shared-libraries, ld

Let's say I have libA.so with version 1.1 and 1.2, both have the same symbols defined.

what happens if myApp need a symbol from libA but mistakenly linked both versions:

```
ld -o myApp -Lpath -lA_1_1 -lA_1_2
```

Am I right it will use symbols from the first one as long as it can find it?

Comment: I think it depends how they are linked, whether the symbol from 1.1 will appear before 1.2 or vice versa. The question is which one will be taken into account (mocks do some magic, by linking mocked library *I think* before all of the symbols)

Comment: However wouldn't it be better if you just tested it yourself? {: Don't seem to be something difficult

Comment: @Melon you are right I can test it myself on my mac, but I'm hoping to get some insight rather than just a yes/no answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Am I right it will use symbols from the first one as long as it can find it?

Yes, in general. And that might not be what you want.

If a function `foo()` in `libA_1_2` calls another public function in the library, `bar()`, then it will use the symbol from `libA_1_1`, which might do the wrong thing (for example if v1.2 of the library was changed so that `foo()` expects `bar()` to deallocate some memory, but the v1.1 version of `bar()` doesn't do that).